# Complicated MySQL Query - Do I Use a Right Join?

Tags: mysql

OK,

I have a table with people (id, name, address, etc.). Which has a one to many relationship with a table employees (id, person_id, salary, department_id, etc.). And the employees all belong to (many to one relationship) different departments (id, title, location, year_id) which are year-specific.

I want to write a query to find the employees who worked in 2013 and exclude those who continue to work for the company in 2014. Basically I want those who worked for the company last year but don't anymore. I made a feeble attempt below.

```
SELECT * FROM people 
JOIN employees ON people.id=employees.person_id 
RIGHT JOIN departments ON employees.department_id=departments.id 
AND departments.year_id='2013'
WHERE departments.year_id<>'2014'
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `not exists` check for those employees who discontinued work in 2014

```
SELECT * FROM people 
JOIN employees e ON people.id=e.person_id 
RIGHT JOIN departments ON e.department_id=departments.id 
WHERE departments.year_id='2013'
AND NOT EXISTS
(SELECT 1
FROM departments 
JOIN employees ee ON ee.department_id=departments.id 
WHERE departments.year_id = '2014'
AND e.id=ee.id 
)
```

Or `not in()` solution but its not recommended due to a dependent sub query

```
SELECT * FROM people 
JOIN employees e ON people.id=e.person_id 
RIGHT JOIN departments ON e.department_id=departments.id 
WHERE departments.year_id='2013'
AND e.id NOT IN
(SELECT ee.id 
FROM departments 
JOIN employees ee ON ee.department_id=departments.id 
WHERE departments.year_id = '2014'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure as to why you have a one to many on people to employees or how this functionality is applied within your system, but if I understand it correctly, this should work.

M Khalid Junaid's answer will likely work however I despise using sub-queries as they do not tend to scale well.  The below should work while returning only 1 row per employee (no groups) in addition it only has 1 left join and no sub-queries.

```
SELECT * FROM people 
JOIN employees ON people.id=employees.person_id 
JOIN departments as dept_start ON employees.department_id=departments.id && departments.year_id = 2013
LEFT JOIN departments as dept_end ON employees.department_id=departments.id && departments.year_id = 2014
WHERE dept_start.id IS NOT NULL && dept_end.id IS NULL
```